# How do i intergrate the vimeo search database to my website?

Tags: php, api, youtube, vimeo

I have to make a website that pulls videos from youtube,vimeo,dailymotion etc. and i dont know where to start.I have Youtube's api already intergrated and vimeo doesn't have a great one,is there anyway i can pull videos from others sites to my site?

Thanks,
Lee

Comment: The Vimeo api seems quite detailed. What are you having trouble with? http://vimeo.com/api

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fond of this kind of stuff, but you could parse html return from a search on vimeo, load the html into DOM and do some xpath query for  tags that have "/0123456789" links.

Or maybe ask them if they have such API, i'm pretty surprised they don't have one to be honnest...